# Error "NameError: name 'self' is not defined" even though I declare "self"

Tags: python-3.x, function, class

I'm coding the AdaBoost from scratch in Python. Could you please elaborate on why the line `self.functions[0] = f_0` causes an error?

```
class AdaBoost_regressor():
    def __init__(self, n_estimators, functions):
        # n_estimators is the number of weak regressors     
        self.n_estimators = n_estimators
        
        # We will store the sequence of functions in object "functions"
        self.functions = np.array([None] * n_estimators, dtype = 'f')
    
    # We set f_0 = 0
    def f_0(x):
        return 0
    self.functions[0] = f_0
```

The result is `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`.

Comment: There is no `self` defined in that class scope. You have `self` defined as a parameter of your `__init__` method, but parameters are local variables, not accessible outside the function. Is that supposed to be inside `__init__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the reason for you error is that you cannot use `self` inside a class outside the methods, since, in order to use `self` an instance of the class have to be passed as a parameter to some function.

Notice that until you initialize your class, there’s no meaning for the expression `self`.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed when self is outside it is read as a variable. If you declare:

```
self = 0
self.functions[0] = f_0
```

the error is gone but "self" would be considered a variable and it is not recommended to declare it. It is the same as if you set the following code:

```
my = 0
my.functions[0] = f_0
```

If you remove "my = 0" it would throw error again.